# Entity framework foreign key not id

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

How do I create a join to another table that is not on the ID of the other table such as:

```
public class Table1 {
   public int Table1ID { get; set; }

   public string LookupVAl1 { get; set; }

   public Table2 Table2Data { get; set; }
}


public class Table2 {
   public int Table2ID { get; set; }

   public string LookupVAl1 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use LookVAl1 as the join and be able to access Table2Data from within Table1 class when I access table 1 object.

To note, LookupVAl1 may not exist in table 2.

Thanks for your time.

Dan

Comment: Did you mean you want `Table2` to be lazy-loaded with `Table1`?

Comment: Yea. So basically if LookupVAl1 exists in both tables, I want to be able to access Table2 data from object within Table1. E.g. Table1.Table2....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - How do I join tables on non-primary key columns in secondary tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284184/entity-framework-how-do-i-join-tables-on-non-primary-key-columns-in-secondary)

Comment: My question wasnt about accessing the data through linq. Quite comfortable with that.

Comment: If i make LookupVAl1 the primary key, how do i then access the data from Table1?

Comment: depends on your approach ... code first/model first/db first?

Comment: the example above is code first

Comment: something like ... modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>().HasOptional(x => x.Table2Data).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.LookupVAl1)